# What happens during the gap between two resources in the Chrome Dev Tools timeline view?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, pageload

Can anybody help me understand what the following is telling me in Chrome Dev Tools on the Network tab Timeline? Specifically, what does the gap mean?

[image: Gap between resources loading]

During this terribly slow page load the resources display some info on how they are loading up until ~7 seconds or so. This is followed by a large gap. And then near ~13 seconds there is info on the resources loading again.

I've truncated the full list of resources, but the only resource bar that spans the gap, is the first resource for the primary page. It it identifies what is happening in the gap as “Content Download” (the blue bar):

[image]

The total resources on the page appear to be around 2.5MB in size. In this example, the `DOMContentLoaded` and `Load` events are taking place at the same time near the ~13 second mark.

Answer (score 0):

Chrome starts loading external resources like images or scripts before the page HTML download has finished.

For example, here I've got an image at the top of the page, and then further down in the middle of the HTML a script tag.

[image: Chrome Network panel]

This also means that the `Load` event follows quickly after `DOMContentLoaded`, because Chrome has already fetched the additional resources.

In your case, there's some JavaScript code that waits for either one of those events and then triggers additional requests.

The reason for the initial 13s load time is that after the waiting time of ~4s it takes another 9s to actually download the whole document.

This could be because the browser's internet connection is poor, or because the server takes a long time to generate the response, or because the server doesn't have enough bandwidth.